# Reliable way to require only bash shell in script

Tags: bash, shell

I wonder if there are any reliable methods (cross-shell compatible) to require `bash` as shell interpreter for my script.

For example, I have shell script that can be run only with `bash` interpreter. Despite of `#!/usr/bin/bash` at the beginning of my script some smart user/hacker can run it directly with another shell: `$ csh script.sh`
This can lead to unwanted consequences.

I already thought about testing `echo $0` output and exiting with error code but syntax for `if` statements (as long as for another conditional statements) is different among various shell interpreters. Testing directly for `$BASH_VERSION` variable is unreliable due to the same limitations.

Are there any cross-shell compatible and reliable way to determine current interpreter?
Thank you!

**EDIT**: as for now I have the following basic check for compatibility:

```
### error codes
E_NOTABASH=1
E_OLD_BASH=2

# perform some checks
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]
then
    echo -e "ERROR: this script support only BASH interpreter! Exiting" >&2
    exit $E_NOTABASH
fi

if [[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -lt 4 ]]
then
    echo -e "ERROR: this script needs BASH 4.0 or greater! Your current version is $BASH_VERSION. Exiting" >&2
    exit $E_OLD_BASH
fi
```

Comment: Is there a real use case for this request?  I doubt it (but am happy to be proven wrong).  If you provide a shell script, all you can do is document that it is meant to be run using `bash`.  The users receiving it can still look at it and execute it manually line by line in any shell they want.  There is no way to avoid that.

Comment: My script is intended to be used on some clusters for parallel computing. I want to possibly eliminate erroneous situation when batch/workload manager tries to run my script via `csh`, for example (or something similar) and doesn't respect sha-bang at the file beginning

Comment: You could just start the correct shell in your script: `/bin/bash -c '` and then let your script follow (without and single quotes!) and at the end have a `'` in the last line.  But still:  There might be shells around which have a different idea of how to parse the single quotes etc.  Anyway, in my test using the `zsh` this worked.

Comment: "...some smart user/hacker can..." completely bypass any solution you come up with.

Comment: Also: "Despite of #!/usr/bin/bash at the beginning of my script..." My machine does not have `/usr/bin/bash`. You might consider `#!/bin/bash` or even `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: `case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[1-3].*) echo "ERROR: This script requires bash 4.0+" >&2; exit 1;; esac` -- all one line, no need for extra checks.

Comment: BTW, note that for your own variables (`E_NOTABASH`, `E_OLD_BASH`), it's good form to use names containing at least one lowercase character. See the POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html specifying that compliant shells and other standard-defined tools will attach meaning only to all-caps names, whereas other names are reserved for application use; since environment and shell variables share a namespace (setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable), this applies to both classes.

Comment: @SiKing, seems like `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is great fail-proof solution for situations when bash is installed into untraditional location!
@Charles Duffy, nice one-liner! Thank you for pointing out POSIX standard, I'll read it and think about some code rewriting...

Comment: I'm sure there was a discussion about cross shell scripting tricks in the internet news group comp.unix.shell over 10 years ago (blush) and included `csh`. The `case` statement seems like a great solution for your purpose, but if you want to know more, maybe you can find a complete archive of comp.unix.shell (Not sure of the state of comp.unix.shell on google groups , but I had read that it was incomplete). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand the scope of the question.

A `#! /usr/bin/env bash` shebang will fail if there's no bash, but to keep it from being explicitly parsed by another shell, um...

How about -

```
case "$BASH_VERSION" in
  4.*) : bash version 4+ so ok ;;
    *) echo "please run only with bash v4+. Aborting."
       exit 1                  ;;
esac
```

If the syntax works, it is either right or hacked.

If it crashes, you're good. :)

Comment: Seems like the best variant to employ

Comment: Only 1/3 of my machines have `/bin/env`, but 3/3 have `/usr/bin/env`.

Answer (score 1):

you could check for the parent process id, command respectively

```
pstree -p $$ | grep -m 1 -oE '^[^\(]+'
```

or

```
ps $(ps -o ppid=$$)
```

Comment: If you need to worry about csh, you probably can't assume that `grep -o` is available.